# Rails. Working with data from existing MS SQL database :(

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first post so please be patient with me... :)

I am learning rails at the moment and took  an internal project to help me and get proper handson practice.

The situation is like this:
We have an existing MS SQL Server 2000 DB with bunch of customers. Usual stuff.
I don't know who designed it but there is a huge table "Customer" where all the details are.

Soon we'll be moving customers out to a new company and need to track the movement.
So the application should have the snapshot of the movement details for a particular customer: whether he was called on the phone, talked to or contacted by other means. Notes of the conversation. Whether he agreed to move. Etc ...

So the original customer data should be pooled from MS SQL and all the new tracking data should be in proper new rails DB.
I was considering few things:
1. Pooling customer records from old DB and doing the rest of the work in the new one.
This one no good as my research shows that rails cannot work with two DBs at the same time.
2. Connecting to just  old MS SQL and doing all the work there creating new necessary tables.
This one seems to be a lot of trouble. "odbc" adapter gives me errors. "sqlserver" adapter does not work with mssql 2000
Plus, I predict lots of troublew working with existing  MS DB.
3. This method I think is the most rational.
Dump the customer table from the old MS SQL DB to CVS and import it to the new sqlite db created for the rails app.

Please let me know if you think of other methods to solve this problem.

With the third method I still see many problems which I would like help if possible.
For instance, rails creates additional fields in the table so the data import might not work. Or am I mistaken?
Is the third method sounds doable for you? Do you see any pitfalls. Suggestions?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unfortunately, ruby doesn't work great on windows, and MSSQL is probably the worst choice for a rails db. Given that I could deploy on MySQL or PG on linux, I would export the data from the old db, and totally start fresh, so write a data import script that shapes things the way rails likes. First step would be to move towards rails conventions, so a Customer model will have a customers table with an auto incrementing primary key field called id that is an integer. All fields use "wide case" (all lower case, with underscores seperating words), and audit fields on all tables that are datetime, and called created_at / updated_at. Definately a pain (especially if you are new to rails), but you will have a hellish time if you try to fight convention and are not at least moderately comfortable with the platform. IMO sqlite is a bad choice for anything other then an app that wont store much data and will be used by only one person.